# How to get results of json using search input to group sub objects into one result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this jQuery code that gets the data on `data.json` file and outputs the result on search box. I'm having trouble into it because when I search the data it outputs like this:

```
Ken
[projects details here]

Ken
[projects details here]
```

What I want to achieve is to group the search result like this:

```
Ken
    [projects details here]
    [projects details here]
```

I guess its probably on my second loop, but how can I alternate the code to get the result that I want?

Here's the full code though:

**data.json**

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "name": "Ken",
            "projects": [
                {
                    "image": "./resources/assets/avatars/uniswap-1.png",
                    "title": "TestKen1",
                    "text_sub": "(USD)",
                    "text_price": "(USD)"
                },
                {
                    "image": "./resources/assets/avatars/uniswap-2.png",
                    "title": "TestKen2",
                    "text_sub": "(USD)",
                    "text_price": "(USD)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Vodka",
            "projects": [
                {
                    "image": "./resources/assets/avatars/uniswap-3.png",
                    "title": "TestVodka1",
                    "text_sub": "(USD)",
                    "text_price": "(USD)"
                },
                {
                    "image": "./resources/assets/avatars/uniswap-4.png",
                    "title": "TestVodka2",
                    "text_sub": "(USD)",
                    "text_price": "(USD)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<style>
    #result {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 870px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 1001;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 0px 25px 45px rgba(18, 16, 50, 0.2);
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .list-group {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 0;
    }

    .link-class:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .list-group-item {
        border-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
    }

    .list-group-item-inline {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
</style>


<br /><br />
<div class="container" style="width:900px;background:#000;padding:20px;">

    <div class="header-search lg-hidden">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
        <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $('#search').keyup(function () {
            $('#result').html('');
            $('#state').val('');
            var searchField = $('#search').val();
            var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < value.length; ++j) {
                            if (value[i].name.search(expression) != -1) {
                                $('#result').append(
                                    '<li class="list-group-item link-class">' +
                                    '<h6 class="fw-400 mb-8">' + value[i].name + '</h6>' +
                                    '<div class="list-group-item-inline">' +
                                    '<img class="mr-6 w-24" src="' + value[i].projects[j].image + '">' +
                                    '<p><b>' + value[i].projects[j].title + '</b> ' + value[i].projects[j].text_sub + '<span class="ml-8">' + value[i].projects[j].text_price + '</p>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '</li>'
                                );
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $('#result').on('click', 'li', function () {
            var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
            $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
            $("#result").html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to start the `<li>` with the name in the outer loop

Comment: @charlietfl could you show example? I find it difficult to output your point of view. Thank you.

Comment: You need to create the string as a variable. Start in outer loop, then loop through ech project adding to the string for each one. Then close the </li> and do the append when all loops complete